# How do you prevent BackgroundTask from being cancelled if it's appears Idle (but is not due to very small regular workload)?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have an app that uses a timer similar to this example code:

[Sample Code for BackgroundTasks](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9)

Specifically the part with a timer. 
So my code runs as intended when I launch the app in debugger. Every minute the event fires and I log to a text file (and do a tile notification).

My problem is when I run it normally without debugging, it runs four times (sometimes five) and then nothing. Looking at the processes running I can see the backgroundtask and then its gone. I've got logging in the OnCancelled even and it's never called. 
I even tried creating a deconstructor for the background task to see if that is called (and put some logging there) and it doesn't seem to be. 
Also no exceptions seem to be thrown, at least they are not logged and I have a try catch around the timer.

Suggestions on how I can track down why the background task seems to be squashed (I thought if the system wants them closed, it cancels them?)

**Update:** I ran the app normally without debugger attached, and when I saw the backgroundtask process appear, I attached my debugger to it. It ran for 8 minutes (where the log was showing previous runs stopped after four). When I detached the debugger at that point it ran a further four times (once per minute) and then the process disappeared.

**Update:** Ok I think I have worked out what is happening, but not why. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh974425.aspx

> When you are not debugging, Windows Process Lifetime Management (PLM) controls the execution state of your app—starting, suspending, resuming, and terminating the app in response to user actions and the state of the device. When you are debugging, Windows disables these activation events.

So I guess this may change my question to how do I find out why Backgroundtask is being suspended when it still has work to do?

**Update:** Worked out my issue, I was attaching Canceled handler to a field variable (which was being assigned in Run method. Attaching Canceled handler directly to the instance passed into Run method made the Cancel call work. I didn't think that would make a difference as its a reference tot he same thing. Anyway, Cancel reason is "IdleTask". Increasing the frequency of the timer seems to make the background task not get cancelled.

So question is now **How much is enough work to not be cancelled due to being Idle?** Can you check for this and adjust? Can you override the check? I don't want to just do work for the sake of not appearing idle. That's going to waste battery life!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem (and found for my app an acceptable workaround).

But your question is interresting and still unanswered:

Although with a BackgroundTaskDeferral sometimes the system assume that the task is idle and cancel the task:

```
BackgroundTaskDeferral defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
while (Task runtime less than 14 minutes and 35 seconds)
{
  ... do something
  // wait 20 seconds
  new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(20000);
}
defferal.Complete();
```

The real task is a little bit more complicated:).

I also don't want to just do work for the sake of not appearing idle.